# Como limitar o intervalo entre duas datas no <input type="month">?

Tags: html, html5

Apesar de serem 3 perguntas creio que todas valem para o mesmo caso sobre o "range/intervalo"

- É possível limitar o "intervalo" entre duas datas no `<input type="month">`?
- Se sim, existe algum padrão de formato obrigatório que devemos seguir ao passar os valores que limitam?
- Este "limite" é suportado por quais navegadores e dispositivos mobile?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> É possível limitar o "intervalo" entre duas datas no `<input type="month">`?

Você pode utilizar os atributos `min` e `max`.

Assim:

```
 <input id="aniversario" type="month" name="aniversario"
     min="1900-01" max="1999-12">
```

> Se sim, existe algum padrão de formato obrigatório que devemos seguir ao passar os valores que limitam?

No caso do `[type=month]`, O formato precisa ser `YYYY-MM` (onde `YYYY` é ano com 4 dígitos e `MM` é o mês com dois dígitos).

> Este "limite" é suportado por quais navegadores e dispositivos mobile?

De acordo com a tabela de compatibilidade do [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/month), o suporte ainda não é completo.

No meu Firefox, por exemplo, não funcionou. E existe um [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=888320) que foi informado a respeito desse input.

Além disso, o Internet Explorer e o Safari também não têm suporte ainda.

No Android, parece que o Firefox também não tem suporte.

<kbd>[image: Tabela de compatibilidade do input type month]</kbd>

## Validação

Além disso, a MDN alerta a respeito da validação de entrada de dados:

> Por padrão, `input[type="month"]` não aplica nenhuma validação aos valores inseridos. As implementações da interface do usuário geralmente não permitem inserir algo que não seja uma data, o que é útil, mas você ainda pode enviar o formulário com a entrada vazia ou inserir uma data inválida (por exemplo, no dia 32 de abril).

## Polyfill

Eu encontrei um [Polyfill](https://github.com/jonstipe/month-polyfill) para o `input[type=month]`, mas parece-me que o mesmo depende de jQuery (coisa que não me agrada muito).

Answer (score 6):

> É possível limitar o "intervalo" entre duas datas no `<input type="month">`?

Sim, é possível limitar o "intervalo" entre duas datas. Para isso você pode usar o atributo `min` e `max`. Veja um exemplo:

```html
<input type="month" value="2018-09" min="2018-01" max="2018-12">
```

No exemplo anterior estamos limitando a pergunta para que o usuário só possa escolher o mês no ano de 2018, entre Janeiro e Dezembro.

> Se sim, existe algum padrão de formato obrigatório que devemos seguir
>   ao passar os valores que limitam?

O padrão de formato obrigatório que devemos seguir ao usar o atributo `min`, `max` ou até mesmo o `value` é o seguinte: `YYYY-MM`.

Onde Y é o ano, no caso 2018, e M é o mês, nesse caso 09. Logo, ficaria: `2018-09`.

> Este "limite" é suportado por quais navegadores e dispositivos mobile?

No Desktop apenas Chrome/Opera e Edge suportam.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No celular a maioria dos navegadores modernos suportam.

Obs.: onde está marcado em vermelho significa que não há suporte, já o verde simboliza que o navegador suporta a tag.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

De acordo com o [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=date%20and%20time) atualmente 86.66% dos navegadores suportam (parcialmente ou totalmente) o atributo, entre desktop e mobile.

**Referências:**

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/month)